# Is there an "or" attribute selector, like input[type=button|text]?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select all `input` elements on a page, but not the ones that are of type `image`, `button` or `submit`. What came to my mind first was selecting all `input` elements that are of type `text`, then all of type `checkbox` etc.

However, this isn't very elegant. I was wondering if there is any better technique here. What would be useful is a selector like `input[type=text|checkbox|radio|password|etc]`, but this does not seem to be available.

I know I can also select all `input`s and then filter them using `.filter()` but is there a more generic selector to select elements having one of a list of attributes?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since you want to include everything *except* a few particular types, try this:

```
$('input:not([type=image],[type=button],[type=submit])')
```

Answer (score 31):

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').stuff();
```

or (taken from comments)

```
$('input:not([type=image],[type=button],[type=submit]')
```

Answer (score 5):

In CSS you can have selectors like:

```
input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio],input[type=password]
```

maybe this works in jQuery as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old, but i feel the best elegant solution for this would be to give them a common class and then use that as a selector ?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are not entirely true.

When depending on a id (#) these methods seems to fail.

In my experience we need to add the id for each `or` statement.

Like so:

```
$('#id input[type=text], #id input[type=checkbox], ...
```